# Whats the proper way to keep track of changes to documents so that client can poll for deltas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, message-queue

I'm storing key-value documents on a mongo collection, while multiple clients are pushing updates to this collection (posting to an API endpoint) at a very fast pace (updates will come in faster than once per second).

I need to expose another endpoint so that a watcher can poll all changes, in delta format, since last poll. Each diff must have a sequence number and/or timestamp.

What I'm thinking is:

- For each update I calculate a diff and store it.
- I store each diff on a mongo collection, with current timestamp (using Node Date object)
- On each poll for changes: get all diffs from the collection, delete them and return.

The questions are:

- Is it safe to use timestamps for sequencing changes?
- Should I be using Mongo to store all diffs as changes are coming or some kind of message queue would be a better solution?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> On each poll for changes: get all diffs from the collection, delete them and return.

This sounds terribly fragile. What if client didn't receive the data (he crashed/network disappeared in the middle of receiving the response)? He retries the request, but oops, doesn't see anything. What I would do is that client remembers last version it saw and asks for updates like this:

```
GET /thing/:id/deltas?after_version=XYZ
```

When it receives a new batch of deltas, it gets the last version of that batch and updates its cached value.

> Is it safe to use timestamps for sequencing changes?

I think so. ObjectId already contains a timestamp, so you might use just that, no need for separate time field.

> Should I be using Mongo to store all diffs as changes are coming or some kind of message queue would be a better solution?

Depends on your requirements. Mongo should work well here. Especially if you'll be cleaning old data.

> at a very fast pace (updates will come in faster than once per second)

By modern standards, 1 per second is nothing. 10 per second - same. 10k per second - now we're talking.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
When you say that the choice for Mongo depends on my requirements, what kind of things should I take in consideration? The system may receive lots changes concurrently, generating high loads of delta objects. It's ok to think that with sharding the potential to handle lots of concurrents requests will be supported by mongo, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sharding is the recommended way to scale write capability. Poorly chosen shard key can prevent this, though, if all writes will land on the "hot" shard, for example. Time-based shard keys tend to do that.